# Is this a virus on my Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, virus, visual-studio-code

[image]

I tried to minimise my Visual Studio window and this happened as I moused over the dock. The screen remained like this for more than a minute. Could this be a virus on my computer?

Comment: It looks to me more like faulty GPU.

Comment: Or a bug in the macOS graphics driver/stack. A virus is highly unlikely, for a lot of reasons (for one: it would need to interfere with the graphics or window manager stack somehow).

Comment: Does a reboot fix this?

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not a typical indication of a virus on your computer.

Could it in theory be a virus? - Yes, in theory.

Is it in any way probable in a practical scenario? - No.